# discord.py "str" has no "disconnect" member

Tags: discord.py

Im trying to make a bot that joins to the vc when some specific person joins. i got the "specific person" part and bot connects fine but when I disconnect, it says "str" has no "disconnect" member(points at last line, "voice" word). I tried messing around with order of parents etc but cant figure it out. little help would be cool

```
voice = ""
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after is not None and member.id in idler:
        
        if not before.channel and after.channel:
            global voice
            channel = member.voice.channel
            
            
            voice = await channel.connect()
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="path"))


        elif before.channel and not after.channel:
            await voice.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`voice` is assigned to "" before the event, `voice` only gets assigned to `await channel.connect()` if the `if` statement is satisfied.

Below is the revised code:

```py
voice = ""
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if after is not None and member.id in idler:
        
        if not before.channel and after.channel:
            global voice
            channel = member.voice.channel
            
            
            voice = await channel.connect()
            voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="path"))


        elif before.channel and not after.channel:
            await before.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
```